# Cluster in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell

How can I define a cluster in Haskell using list comprehension?
I want to define a function for the cluster :

```
 ( a b c ) = [ a <- [1 .. 10],b<-[2 .. 10], c = (a, b)]
```

Comment: What do you mean by cluster? You can't have `c = (a,b)` and also `a b c`. Did you mean `(a,b,c)` as the output? Can you give an example?

Comment: `a <- [1 .. 10],b<-[2 .. 10], b > a` would be better as `a <- [1 .. 10],b<-[a+1 .. 10]`

Comment: Here is an example of output :[(1,2,1),(1,3,1),(1,4,1),(1,5,1),(1,6,1),(1,7,1)]

Answer (score 2):

In your comment you gave the example `[(1,2,1),(1,3,1),(1,4,1),(1,5,1),(1,6,1),(1,7,1)]`.

In that example, only the middle number changes, the other two are always 1. You can do this particular one with

```
ones = [(1,a,1)| a<-[1..7]]
```

However, you might want to vary the other ones. Let's have a look at how that works, but I'll use letters instead to make it clearer:

```
> [(1,a,b)| a<-[1..3],b<-['a'..'c']]
[(1,1,'a'),(1,1,'b'),(1,1,'c'),(1,2,'a'),(1,2,'b'),(1,2,'c'),(1,3,'a'),(1,3,'b'),(1,3,'c')]
```

You can see that the letters are varying more frequently than the numbers - the `b<-[1..3]` is *like* an outer loop, with `c<-['a'..'c']` being the inner loop.

You could copy the `c` into the first of the three elements of the tuple:

```
> [(b,a,b)| a<-[1..3],b<-['a'..'b']]
[('a',1,'a'),('b',1,'b'),('a',2,'a'),('b',2,'b'),('a',3,'a'),('b',3,'b')]
```

Or give each its own varying input

```
>  [(a,b,c)| a<-[1..2],b<-['a'..'b'],c<-[True,False]]
[(1,'a',True),(1,'a',False),(1,'b',True),(1,'b',False),(2,'a',True),(2,'a',False),(2,'b',True),(2,'b',False)]
```